# replace of a listview with onclick listener doesnot work

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i am trying to replace a fragment listview with a new fragment when i am use onclicklistener. However, when i click in one of the listview items change fragment but the listview appers below. Here my code:

changing listview fragment

```
            ent_qtb_operaciones user   = listaqtb_operaiones.get(pos);
            qtb_operaciones_deta fragment = new qtb_operaciones_deta(); 
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            bundle.putSerializable("usuario",user); // use as per your need
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.qtb_listview_layout,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

the fragment which receive inforamaition

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qtb_operacion_base, container, false);
    return vista;


}
```

As result, Second fragment superpose first one but listview of first fragment does not desappair

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s handle only `View`s that belong to `Fragment`s. They will not remove or replace any other `View`s that you might have in your layout.

Comment: Thanks Mike. In my layout i have a framelayout in both xml files and also I have extended my two classes from fragment.

Comment: However when i use onclick listener of the listview no replace the fragment only superimpose it

Comment: We'd need more information to be able to give you a specific answer. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.